# When is the product of the derivatives equal to the derivative of the product?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

It's already well known that the derivative of a product is not just the product of the derivatives in *general*, but I'm looking for specific pairs of functions where taking the product of the derivatives does work. $$f'g'=f'g+fg'$$ I tried the simpler case where $f'$ or $g'$ or both are zero, which results in the solutions $$f(x)=A,\,g(x)=B$$ $$f(x)=0,\,g(x) = g(x)$$ but if I assume $f'\not=0 ,g'\not=0$ then I rearrange the equation $$f'g'=f'g+fg'$$
$$f'g'-fg'=f'g$$ $$(f'-f)g'=f'g$$ $$\frac{g'}{g}=\frac{f'}{f'-f}$$ $$\int\frac{g'}{g}=\int\frac{f'}{f'-f}$$ $$\ln g=\int\frac{f'}{f'-f}$$ If I assume that $f'$ is proportional to $f$, then $f'=Cf$, so $$\ln g=\int\frac{f'}{Cf-f}=\int\frac{f'}{(C-1)f}=\frac{1}{-1+C}\int\frac{f'}{f}$$  $$\ln g=\frac{1}{-1+C}\ln f+D$$ $$\ln g=\ln f^{\frac{1}{-1+C}}+D$$
$$g=f^{\frac{1}{-1+C}}*e^D$$ $$g=Af^{\frac{1}{-1+C}}$$ but since I assumed $f'=f$, then $f=Be^{Cx}$ and $g=AB^{\frac{1}{-1+C}}e^{(\frac{C}{-1+C})x}=B_2e^{(\frac{C}{-1+C})x}$ If I assume a more complicated relationship between $f'$ and $f$, I can get more complicated pairs, such as $e^\frac 1x$ and $e^{-\arctan(x)}$, but that's a bit of a guessing game. I'm left with two questions:

1. Do all the solutions involve the exponential?
2. Is there a way to find the general solution to this equation?

Comment: Consider the case that $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = (x+2)^2$. It does not involve the exponential.

Comment: (Generically speaking) you have already found the general solution: $g=exp\int\frac{f'}{f'+f}$. For any $f$ there is a $g$ such that $(fg)'=f'g'$. With one relation between two unknowns $(f,g)$ one cannot expect anything more specific I would say.